# Click on a button don't display the WebView

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm developing an app in react-native and i'm confronted to a problem:

I want that when i click on a button ( or directly the View where the button is ) a Webview is shown on screen and open the link directly passed in parameters.
But nothing happens.

Here is my code:

```
return (
            <ScrollView style={[style.case1]} refreshControl={<RefreshControl refreshing={this.state.refreshing} onRefresh={this.handleRefresh} />} >
                {
                    this.state.orders.map(function (order) {
                        let a = _this.getPosts(order);
                        let Final = _this.splitString(a.message," ");
                        return (
                        <View style={[style.case2]} key={a.message} >
                            <Couleur couleur={Final[4]} />
                            <Text style={[style.Nom]} >Nom : {Final[1]}</Text>
                            <Text style={[style.Nom]} >Numéro de build : {Final[2]}</Text>
                            <Button onPress={<Web url={Final[3]} />}  title="Click"/>
                        </View>
                    );
                })}
            </ScrollView>
        );
```

And the WebView class :

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {WebView} from "react-native";

export default class Web extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        let uri = this.props.url;
        return(
            <WebView
                ref={(ref) => {this.webview = ref;}}
                source={{uri}}
                style={{marginTop:20}}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

And i got this error :

> "Object is not a function(evaluating 'this.props.onPress(e)')

I would be very happy if someone help me ! :)

Comment: have you try to change like this `onPress={() => return <Web url={Final[3]} />}` ?

Comment: I have an error when i type your solution, but if i remove the 'return ', i don't have any errors now.

Comment: But i still don"t have the WebView displayed. Thanks for helping me

Comment: i have try to do that, i put the web view into modal, and i call the modal using button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The onPress action needs to be a function that does something. Right now, you are setting the action to a component and react doesn't know what to do with that.

Without some kind of navigation library controlling your views, you could do something like have the onPress set some state that controls a part of the render function that either shows your existing page or the new 'Web' component.

So make onPress like:
`onPress={e => this.setState({showWebPart:true})}`

Then in your current render function you could have a ternary like:

```
{this.state.showWebPart ? <Web url={Final[3]} /> : ..current render stuff}
```